# How to Join the column which is present in the Same Table

Tags: join

Actually im try to Join the column which is present on same table.
Here is the scenario ,

PROBLEM :

```
   Column_1   column_2  column_1_data   column_2_date
     null       null      data1         data2
     data       data       null          null
```

Expected Ouput:

```
   Column_1   column_2  
     data1      data2      
     data       data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT COALESCE(Column_1,column_1_data) as Column_1, 
COALESCE(Column_2,column_2_date) as column_2 
FROM yourTable
```

This way you get the data from `Column_1` if it is not `null`, otherwise it takes from `column_1_data`. Same for `Column_2`